# Add new language to localization list in Xcode 3.1

Tags: xcode, localization, internationalization, xcode3.1

In Xcode I'm trying to add another localization to an xib file. In the drop-down list I have 4 languages:

- English
- Japanese
- French
- German.

How do I add Chinese to the list so I don't have to type it every time when I add to another xib file?

Answer (score 1):

You have to type it every time. This is unfortunately hard-coded into Xcode. As best I can tell, they hard-coded it in DevToolsCore (a private framework that Xcode uses, and one of the usual suspects for hard-coded strings).

What's funny is that Xcode even notes this new entry in the project file (look for "knownRegions"). It just doesn't use it for the drop-down.

I recommend opening a radar.